# pandas nested dict to flat dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I have a dict:

```
d = {12 : [8,2,3,4]
     15 : [6,1,9,2]}
```

I want to transform it to a flat dataframe:

```
df = val  0 1 2 3 
     12   8 2 3 4
     15   6 1 9 2
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Or: `pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient='index')`

Comment: d = {12 : [8,2,3,4],
     15 : [6,1,9,2]}


pd.DataFrame(d).T